# Puppet max clients

Tags: puppet

I'm just looking for some advice on puppet.  Mainly what everyone uses for their puppet master's hardware and whether or not there is a limit on the maximum number of nodes that a puppet master can serve.

I'm looking at setting up a puppet cluster to manage a few thousand servers and was curious how much hardware I would need to throw at this project.

Comment: It wildly depends on the complication of your manifests.  Do you use server-side functions? What do they do? Storeconfigs? How many resources will you have in your catalogs.  Those are all valid questions.   We can run ~500 clients per master using apache and passenger.  We make extensive use of server side functions, but we don't use storeconfigs.  Storeconfigs adds a huge overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not manage much servers ( less than 10 ) for the moment, so I cannot help you much, 
but if scaling is a issue, you can have a masterless deployment, using git and running puppet with cron ( http://current.workingdirectory.net/posts/2011/puppet-without-masters/ ).

You just need to deploy your config, using cron ( and the vcs of your choice ), and to apply it, using cron too ( or fabric, or mcollective ). Then the only thing that need to scale is the vcs server, and this is much easier to do. You can even simply use rsync or nfs, and I think serving a few thousand server would not be a problem.

However, the issue would be stored configs.